# How to "reverse engineer" a simple react component to pure jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

The following react component here:

http://engineering.kapost.com/2018/05/horizontal-react-component-slider/

Working example for the react component: https://codesandbox.io/s/nkm614n740?from-embed

I have been trying to figure out how to convert this into a simplified jquery component/function, but I just can't get around some of the functions that are working in react out of the box.

Here is the full code below:

```
this.state = {
  marginLeft: 0,
};

renderLeftArrow = () => {
  if (this.state.marginLeft !== 0) {
    return (
      <button className="caret caret-left" onClick={this.handleLeftClicked}>
        {this.props.renderLeftArrow()}
      </button>
    );
  }
  return null;
 }

const remainingWidth = contentWidth - (sliderWidth) - currentMarginLeft;

handleLeftClicked = () => {
  const currentMarginLeft = this.state.marginLeft;
  const sliderWidth = this.slider.offsetWidth;
  let marginLeft;

  if (currentMarginLeft > sliderWidth) {
    marginLeft = currentMarginLeft - sliderWidth;
  } else {
    marginLeft = 0;
  }
   this.setState({ marginLeft });
 }

handleRightClicked = () => {
  const currentMarginLeft = this.state.marginLeft;
  const sliderWidth = this.slider.offsetWidth
  const contentWidth = this.sliderContent.offsetWidth;
  const remainingWidth = contentWidth - (sliderWidth - arrowWidth) - currentMarginLeft;
  let marginLeft;


  if (remainingWidth > 0) {
    if (remainingWidth <= sliderWidth) {
      marginLeft = currentMarginLeft + remainingWidth;
    } else {
      marginLeft = currentMarginLeft + sliderWidth;
    }
  } else {
    marginLeft = currentMarginLeft;
  }
  this.setState({ marginLeft });
 };

componentDidMount() {
 window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize());
 this.resetMargin();
}

componentWillUnmount() {
 window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleResize());
}
```

**Below is what I was able to achieve thus far trying to 'reverse-engineer' it. Looks like its somewhat working but could use some pointers...**

[Also in JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pwameu34/)

```js
$(".nav-menu").css('margin-left', '0px');
var navWrapper = $("#js-nav-menu-wrapper"),
  sliderWidth = navWrapper.outerWidth(),
  contentWidth = navWrapper.children('.nav-menu').outerWidth(),
  currentMarginLeft = parseFloat(navWrapper.children('.nav-menu').css('margin-left')),
  remainingWidth,
  setMargin;

var updateSlider = function() {


  if ('#js-nav-menu-wrapper') {
    sliderWidth = navWrapper.outerWidth();
    contentWidth = navWrapper.children('.nav-menu').outerWidth();
    currentMarginLeft = parseFloat(navWrapper.children('.nav-menu').css('margin-left'));
    remainingWidth = contentWidth - sliderWidth - currentMarginLeft;

    console.log(remainingWidth);
    return this;

  } else {
    navWrapper.children('.nav-menu').css('margin-left', '0px');
  }
};

var navMenuScrollRight = function() {

  updateSlider();

  if (currentMarginLeft > sliderWidth) {
    setMargin = currentMarginLeft - sliderWidth;
  } else {
    setMargin = 0;
  }

  navWrapper.children('.nav-menu').css({
    marginLeft: setMargin
  });

};

var navMenuScrollLeft = function() {

  updateSlider();

  if (remainingWidth > 0) {
    if (remainingWidth <= sliderWidth) {
      setMargin = currentMarginLeft + remainingWidth;
    } else {
      setMargin = currentMarginLeft + sliderWidth;
    }
  } else {
    setMargin = currentMarginLeft;
  }

  navWrapper.children('.nav-menu').css({
    marginLeft: setMargin
  });

};


$('#js-scroll-right').click(function() {

  navMenuScrollRight();

  event.preventDefault();
});

$('#js-scroll-left').click(function() {

  navMenuScrollLeft();

  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.main-menu {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  overflow: initial;
  -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
  transition: 1s all;
}

.nav-menu-wrapper {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 1 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 1 100%;
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav-menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  -ms-flex: 0 1 100%;
  flex: 0 1 100%;
  transition: margin 0.5s ease-out 0s;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-menu li {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  min-width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #f3f3f3; 
}

.nav-padel-left,
.nav-padel-right {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-width:50px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main-menu">
  <div id="js-scroll-left" class="nav-padel-left"><<</div>
  <div id="js-nav-menu-wrapper" class="nav-menu-wrapper">
    <ul class="nav-menu js-nav-built" style="margin-left: 0px;">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
      <li>Item 5</li>
      <li>Item 6</li>
      <li>Item 7</li>
      <li>Item 8</li>
      <li>Item 9</li>
      <li>Item 10</li>
      <li>Item 11</li>
      <li>Item 12</li>
      <li>Item 13</li>
      <li>Item 14</li>
      <li>Item 15</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="js-scroll-right" class="nav-padel-left">>></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried? What exactly are you struggling with? How much do you know about how React works, so you can do a similar thing with jQuery?

Comment: Is this some work you got and you're trying to set someone up to do it for you, for free?

Comment: @vsync not really I am just doing this for a personal project. Are you looking to get paid for this? :)

Comment: @GregL I have tried to convert it to jquery function but since this is a complete react based, there are some functions that needs to be written in jquery, basically this may need to be designed in pure jquery.

Comment: @webkitfanz So you are doing a personal project where you want to swap from a modern React component to rewriting it in jQuery? What for? If you don't want to/can't use React for whatever reason, then just look for a pure-jQuery slider that does the same thing. There must be lots of them out there.

Comment: @GregL I looked everywhere, there are none! If you can find it I will accept it as an answer.

Comment: This isn't actually too hard, since the only state is the `marginLeft`. Just copy the code as is, remove the `extends React.Component` bit, change all the JSX to jQuery DOM manipulation, and call `this.render()` in the constructor. That should get you on the right track. Once you have made progress, post again if you get stuck with the specific problem.

Comment: @GregL so I followed your instructions as best as I could, edited my post with what I was able to achieve so far, looks like its working in reverse...any pointers?

Comment: Uploading your code to jsfiddle and posting a link will probably help you getting an answer

Comment: Here is JS fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/pwameu34/

Comment: Converting FROM React TO jQuery - I thought I'd seen everything :).

Comment: @ElliotNelson poor choice of words on my part, corrected it! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so you had your logic reversed at some points that I fixed. Some notes:

- I'm not sure what `if ('#js-nav-menu-wrapper') {` was supposed to do, but it will always evaluate to true. If this was something that you really want to check for some reason, recheck this.
- Most of your initialization variables are unnecessary as they will get their values set the first time `updateSlider` is called

This is not a full version, to finish you should hide arrows when on maximum amount on either side, and show them again when leaving the extremes.

```
$(".nav-menu").css('margin-left', '0px');
var navWrapper = $("#js-nav-menu-wrapper"),
  sliderWidth = navWrapper.outerWidth(),
  contentWidth = navWrapper.children('.nav-menu').outerWidth(),
  currentMarginLeft = parseFloat(navWrapper.children('.nav-menu').css('margin-left')),
  setMargin;

var max = (navWrapper.children('.nav-menu').outerWidth() - sliderWidth) * -1;

var updateSlider = function() {
  sliderWidth = navWrapper.outerWidth();
  contentWidth = navWrapper.children('.nav-menu').outerWidth();
  currentMarginLeft = parseFloat(navWrapper.children('.nav-menu').css('margin-left'));
};

var navMenuScrollRight = function() {

  updateSlider();

  if (currentMarginLeft * -1 + sliderWidth < contentWidth ) {
    setMargin = Math.max(currentMarginLeft - sliderWidth, max);
  } else {
    setMargin = currentMarginLeft;
  }

  navWrapper.children('.nav-menu').css({
    marginLeft: setMargin
  });

};

var navMenuScrollLeft = function() {

  updateSlider();

  if (currentMarginLeft < 0) {
    setMargin = Math.min(currentMarginLeft + sliderWidth, 0);
  } else {
    setMargin = currentMarginLeft;
  }

  navWrapper.children('.nav-menu').css({
    marginLeft: setMargin
  });

};


$('#js-scroll-right').click(function(e) {

  navMenuScrollRight();

  e.preventDefault();
});

$('#js-scroll-left').click(function(e) {

  navMenuScrollLeft();

  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Shouldn't be hard finishing from here. Good Luck

[Link to fiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/f4g5pmbL/)

Comment: Thanks, this is very close to what I was after, but what value do I set the Math.max, the React version in my first post has a nice way to stop at the very edge, how do I achieve that?

Comment: @webkitfanz you need to calculate the width of everything and the width of the visible container. The max value of margin will be everything - visible.

Comment: I tried the following: https://jsfiddle.net/f4g5pmbL/ but it looks like it only goes to about 80%; not sure how to calculate this, its very tricky...

Comment: Ok I updated the answer. Its actually really simple.

Comment: Thank you, it was a needle in a haystack for me, thanks for all your help! If you have a paypal donation link let me know :)

Comment: @webkitfanz I don't, but you can give me the bounty

Comment: I thought it would do it automatically by accepting your answer, looks like I was wrong. I had to click on the number to pass the bounty to you. Very weird UX design...

Comment: Okay, thank you again, I had another issue with your script, its not working in IE for some reason, IE10 to be specific, do you know what could be the reason?

Comment: Nop, haven't worried about IE in a long time

Comment: I think I actually figured it out, I am going to get the width of each children and just add them up for the slider width. IE has problem finding outerwidth...